# Взаимодействие между двумя разными tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Проблема заключается в следующем: У меня есть два разных tableView на двух разных VC: Первый - отображает список продуктов , второй - список фильтров для этих продуктов (на каждой ячейке стоит checkmark). Как только пользователь убирает чекмарк , список продуктов должен быть скрыт , и соответственно наоборот. Данные для обоих tableView берутся из сети. Не могу понять как можно сделать взаимодействие между двумя tableView

ViewController продуктов:

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class DrinksViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    private var coctails = [Cocktail]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        getCoctails(with: "Beer")
      
    }
    
    func getCoctails(with category: String) {
        Service.shared.getAllCocktails(value: "filter.php?c=" + category) { coctails in
            self.coctails = coctails
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
}
extension DrinksViewController: UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //code
        return coctails.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DrinksCell") as! DrinksCell
        //  cell.DrinkLabel?.text = coctails[indexPath.row].name
        
        let cocktail = coctails[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCocktail(cocktail: cocktail)
        
        return cell
        
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
    
}
```

ViewController для фильтров:

```
import UIKit

class FiltersViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var filtersTableView: UITableView!
    
    
    var filtersList = [Filter]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        filtersTableView.delegate = self
        filtersTableView.dataSource = self
        getFilters(with: "list")
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationItem.title = "Filters"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        print(filtersList.count)
    }
    
    func getFilters(with category: String) {
        Service.shared.getAllFilters(value: "list.php?c=" + category) { filtersList in
            self.filtersList = filtersList
            self.filtersTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

extension FiltersViewController: UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //code
        return filtersList.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FiltersCell") as! FiltersCell
        let filter = filtersList[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureFilter(filter: filter, with: true)
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        return cell
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
        {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
            
        }
        else
        {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
        }
    }
    
}
```

Надеюсь на поддержку более опытных коллег. Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать аналог прослойки между основным и фильтрующим списками `extension`. В `ViewController` где лежит основной список делаем такую штуку:

```
extension YouVCName : ProdFiltering{
    func applyNewFilters(filters:[String:String]?){
        
        
    }
}
```

`ProdFiltering` это протокол который будет размещен в фильтрующем vc:

```
protocol ProdFiltering {
    func applyNewFilters(filters:Dictionary<String,String>?)
}
```

и дальше при переходе на фильтрующий VC с основного экрана нужно передать информацию о том что мы готовы обработать фильтр на данном VC:

```
notesFilter.delegate = self
```

дальше я приведу пример того как у меня реализовано это в общем при переходе, чтобы было понятнее:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Notepad", bundle: nil)
guard let notesFilter = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "NotesFilter") as? NotesFilter else { return}
        
notesFilter.filterData = self.notesFilter
notesFilter.currentFilters = self.filters
notesFilter.delegate = self
        

self.show(notesFilter, sender: nil)
```

дальше в фильтрующем VC делаем переменную:

```
var delegate:ProdFiltering?
```

и дальше при покидании VC мы вызываем эту переменную и передаем данные:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        
        if self.isMovingFromParent {
            self.delegate?.applyNewFilters(filters: currentFilters)
        }
    }
```

данные как вы понимаете можно передавать разные. При получении данных можно их применять в запросе и перезагрузить список. Так же не забудьте что нужно будет передать значения фильтров и на экран фильтров тоже чтобы видеть текущую ситуацию в списке.